# Java Daemon For Reading Email and Creating JIRA Ticket?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, daemon, jira

So what I need is basically to create a java program that runs from command line and will continue to run until I decide to stop it.  The goal of this program is to read email from a particular email address and create JIRA tickets using the contents of the email.

IE: subject of email will be title.  Body will be description. Etc...

I am getting confused with how to go about with the design of how to do this.  I know I can use JavaMail to gain access to the emails right?  Then I just have to parse the email. But other than that I am a little stuck on how I should be making the JIRA Ticket

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use JIRA's built-in service for creating issues from email ? See http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Creating+Issues+and+Comments+from+Email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is an ideal use case for [esb](/questions/tagged/esb) like [mule](/questions/tagged/mule) or [spring-integration](/questions/tagged/spring-integration). Basically these [eip](/questions/tagged/eip) frameworks provide all building blocks you just need to connect.

First you need to define [mail inbound](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#mail). This component will automatically connect to an mail inbox and fetch all new messages.

Then define a [transformation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#messaging-transformation-chapter) from e-mail message to [json](/questions/tagged/json) object. Finally POST that object using [HTTP outbound](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#http). You can create ticket in JIRA using [`/rest/api/2/issue`](http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#id161572) API method.

whole workflow can be implemented almost without coding. Of course you can do everything manually (using [javamail](/questions/tagged/javamail) and [httpclient](/questions/tagged/httpclient)), but then threading, error handling and retrying is up to you.

Comment: Cool thanks a lot.  I can use mule, but I think I need to do it manually using javamail and httpclient so I will look into how to do it with those more.

Answer (score 1):

For the future - if you're confused what requests are sent and so on - use Google Chrome.

Press `Ctrl+Shift+I`->Network and make request. If you need to login before etc. it is the same.

For handling HTTP requests (POST, GET, etc.) I recommend to use [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) or if you need to use JavaScript [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/).

So answer is this:
- Track what requests are made when you do certain things via web browser
- implements the same in Java code using HttpClient or HtmlUnit

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will use that for sure